# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] error on validation

Tags: laravel

Laravel gived error when I added a unique:citizens validation to my code

I run

```php
DB::select("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name;")
```

in artisan tinker and it shows that table "citizens" exists

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required | unique:citizens',
        'phone' => 'alpha_dash | unique:citizens | nullable',
        'organization_id' => '',
        'description' => '',
    ]);

    Citizen::create($data);

    return redirect(route('citizen.index'));
}
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: citizens (SQL: select >count(*) as aggregate from "citizens " where "phone" = 123-1234)

Comment: I know this shouldn't be of an issue - but remove spaces before and after `|`

Comment: Well it turns out it is an issue, thanks. Works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove spaces before and after `|`.

There can't be any characters in there, otherwise, they'll be considered as parts of table names or rules.